# How can I use a login form and a register form on the same page in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am working with the `forms.py` file and I want to have both login and register forms on the same page. I expected Django to handle `<input>` ids for each form.

For instance, I want a username `<input>` inside `<form id="register_form">` to become `<input ... id="register_form_username">`, but it becomes `<input ... id="id_username">`. Now, a username `<input>` inside `<form id="login_form">` will also become `<input ... id="id_username">`.

Because of that, my browser prints "[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #id_username" in the developer tools console.

#### forms.py

```py
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=64)
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=64, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=64)
    email = forms.CharField(label="Email", max_length=64, widget=forms.EmailInput)
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=64, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm = forms.CharField(label="Confirm Password", max_length=64, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

#### views.index

```py
context = {
    "forms": {
        "login": LoginForm(),
        "register": RegisterForm(),
    }
}

return render(request, "orders/index.html", context)
```

#### index.html

```html
<form id="register_form" method="POST" action="/register">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ forms.register }}
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>

<form id="login_form" method="POST" action="/login">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ forms.login }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Actually what you want is [prefixes for forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms).

Comment: @PedramParsian Yes, but is I want a way that doesn't raise warnings in the console.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That's the perfect solution! Thanks a lot!